# Values in the response of api are empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot

ResponseInJsonFormat is a class,

```
@Builder
@Getter
public class ResponseInJsonFormat {

    // Id field in Eloqua
    private String id;

    // List of field values
    private List<FieldValues> fieldValues;
}
```

And FieldValues is also a class defined as,

```
@Builder
@Setter
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class FieldValues {

    // id of the parameter
    private String ID;

    // parameters
    private String type;

    // Value :-  value of the parameter
    private String value;

}
```

I'm writing an api ,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/service/XYZService", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseInJsonFormat sendData(@RequestParam String a) {


        FieldValues parameter = FieldValues.builder()
                .ID(FIELD_ID)
                .type(FILED_TYPE)
                .value(a)
                .build();

List<FieldValues> values = Arrays.asList(parameter);

ResponseInJsonFormat response = ResponseInJsonFormat .builder()
                .fieldValues(values)
                .id(ID)
                .build();

    // need to return ResponseInJsonFormat 
return response

    }
```

But when I call to a service it returns something like,

```
{
    "id": "110",
    "fieldValues": [
        {}
    ]
}
```

Could somebody assist about this empty json object of fieldValues.
I havnt understand why to put @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY) 
if I dont use this annotation I get an error as,

```
no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

So I used the annotation, the error has gone but getting empty value for the same, even though the value is explicitly assigned.

I do not understand why to do all this it just being a list.
Is there any document I should read about,please advice.

If I'm not wrong, spring return the response in JSON format. Then why to do all this.

Comment: since fields are private, need public getter methods to make them visible @user

Comment: does this work? or i will delete my answer?