# Bit confused with @JsonAutoDetect, ObjectMapper()

Tags: spring, spring-boot

With reference to my [previous linked in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212573/values-in-the-response-of-api-are-empty?noredirect=1#comment90549918_51212573) I'm bit confused with the usability of `@JsonAutoDetect`.

I solved the problem by adding `@Getter` to FieldValues class and removed the `@JsonAutoDetect`.

So now it let me thinking, what would be the scenario where `@JsonAutoDetect` can be used, as I can achieve the same result without having it. What is the purpose of having `@JsonAutoDetact` annotation over having getter methods. Am I missing something.

Not able to write any comment for previous question so created a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that I think can help you. The url is  https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonmappingexception .

At my point, if you use `jackson-databind` jar, spring underlying use `ObjectMapper` to serialize JavaBean. If neither javaBean's field nor getter method is public, spring could not serialize JavaBean automaticlly. Annotation `@JsonAutoDetect` is used to custom your javaBean, by which way you can set field limits to any level (e.g. protected public private... so that you can serialize the javaBean successfully).

If I don't understand wrong, the `@Getter` is from `lombok` that automaticlly help you generate public getter method.